# Python Spin Once Equivalent

Tags: ros, rospy, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an equivalent to *spin_once* (C++) in ROS for Python?

In C++ I have a loop with *spin_once* and during each iteration of the loop the code checks a couple of global variables for changes and then does some action based on the value of those global variables. The global variables are based on messages from other nodes' topics to which my C++ ROS node is subscribed. How would this code structure translate into Python?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110336/python-spin-once-equivalent/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is no spin_once in rospy. In rospy the subscriber's callbacks are executed in separate threads. Google quickly produces these old questions including answers:

- http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/rospy-version-of-spinOnce-td180442.html
- http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/ros-spinOnce-equivalent-for-rospy-td2317347.html
- http://answers.ros.org/question/30490/rospy-suscriber-run-a-callback-once-using-rospyspin/

To translate your loop from C++ you could either check periodically in a loop in the main thread, or check in each of the callbacks. Either way you likely need some thread synchronization.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-01-12**:
Nabble doesn't work any longer, but I was able to find this one (it's nice the nabble url contained some searchable text, though this once has a date encoded) http://lists.ros.org/lurker/message/20110123.210157.d2c85cc6.html

> You don't need spinOnce in rospy as the I/O is multithreaded.
> You can use the Rate object to contrain the rate of processing, though it does not have the same effect as spinOnce in roscpp.
>
> - Ken

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospy function [wait_for_message()](https://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message) allowed me to receive one message from topic in Python.

---

Originally posted by [byque](https://answers.ros.org/users/39091/byque/) with karma: 31 on 2019-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-05-19**:
Exactly what I wanted, thanks.

I have used below code:

```
msg = rospy.wait_for_message("/camera/depth/color/points", PointCloud2, timeout=None)
```

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2020-10-02**:
Please note that wait_for_message does the following internally: it subscribes to the topic, waits for a message, then unsubscribes. This is *only* useful if you want to get an odd message once in a while. Don't do this in a loop - it will stress the ros master and all nodes publishing on that topic, and you'll lose all the messages between unsubscribing and subscribing again.